# switch labels expected after this token

Tags: java, android

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    int record_position = null;
    case R.id.Button01:
        // Get all contacts
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
        if (record_position == null){
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                record_position = c.getPosition();
                DisplayContact(c);
            }
        }
        else if (c.moveToPosition(record_position)){     
            c.moveToNext();
            record_position = c.getPosition();
            DisplayContact(c);
        }
        else {
            if(c.moveToFirst){
                record_position = c.getPosition();
                DisplayContact(c);
            }
        }
        db.close();
        break;
    }
}
```

Why do i get this error? What is the problem? What is going wrong?Why do i get this error? What is the problem? What is going wrong?

Comment: In the future post the error.

Comment: It's a compilation error. He is writing code in switch block rather than in the case block.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a variable before the first case block.

Move the variable deceleration to be above the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Move the variable out of the case switch:

```
int record_position = null;
...
public void onClick(View v) {


    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.Button01:
        // Get all contacts
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
        if (record_position == null){
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                record_position = c.getPosition();
                DisplayContact(c);
            }
        }
        else if (c.moveToPosition(record_position)){     
            c.moveToNext();
            record_position = c.getPosition();
            DisplayContact(c);
        }
        else {
            if(c.moveToFirst){
                record_position = c.getPosition();
                DisplayContact(c);
            }
        }
        db.close();
        break;
    }
}
```